# RecyclerView notifyDataSetChanged() changes the image resource of the ImageView on the ListItem

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` List in which every `ListItem` has an ImageView that can have two states. **Note: It changes the Image Resource when pressing from default Image A to Image B.**

When removing a `listItem` after pressing it changes the Image Resource back to the default Image. Why is that?

That bug only applies to the list items with positions lower then the removed. My guess is that the `notifyDataSetChanged()` respectively the `notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, listItems.size())` method creates the listItems new. How can I prevent it?

To remove an Item:

```
private void removeAt() {
    mListItems.remove(pos);
    notifyItemRemoved(pos);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, mListItems.size());
}
```

Comment: Can you please put the relevant code from your adapter please?

Comment: Once you remove an object (or a `ListItem`) from the list, you already notify the adapter that it is removed. I do not get the last line in which you additionally warn the adapter that a set of data is changed. If you are removing only one `ListItem`, then, why notifying a set of data change?

Comment: You are not suppose to do this  notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, mListItems.size());,.As notifyItemRemoved will notify the adapter.Why to notify twice .